# Google Map : Auto suggested address issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using "google direction matrix api" to generated direction route between two address points including waypoints. To take address input from user, I am using google's [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete).

```
 var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'UK'}
};
var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText,options);
```

**Issue** : This happen only with some addresses

> > When user start typing like **terminal** and select address from google suggested address **"Terminal 2, Hounslow, United Kingdom"**

Suppose this is Source address and another address is "London, UK". After filling these addresses and when I click on "Generate Map" button. An error popup ***"Direction request failed due to NOT_FOUND"***.

But if I change address "Terminal 2, Hounslow, United Kingdom" to **"Terminal Two, Hounslow, United Kingdom"** manually (changing numeric value "2" to alphabet "two"). It works fine.

I dont know why this is happen ? while "Terminal 2, Hounslow, United Kingdom" is auto suggested by the Google.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the autocomplete input, I can suggest using the places IDs in Distance Matrix requests instead of the texts.

When user selects a place you can store the corresponding place ID and use it later in distance matrix calculation.

E.g.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Terminal%202%2C%20Hounslow%2C%20United%20Kingdom&components=country%3AGB&key=YOUR_API_KEY

will return place ID ChIJu8J5RChydkgROPKSCZojxCg

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=London%2C%20UK&key=YOUR_API_KEY

will return place ID ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI

Now execute Distance Matrix request for place IDs:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=place_id%3AChIJu8J5RChydkgROPKSCZojxCg&destinations=place_id%3AChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&key=YOUR_API_KEY

The response is:

```
{
    "destination_addresses":[
       "London, UK"
     ],
     "origin_addresses":[
         "London Heathrow Terminal 2, Compass Centre, Nelson Road, Longford, Hounslow TW6 2GW, UK"
     ],
     "rows":[
         {
             "elements":[
                 {
                     "distance":{
                         "text":"28.7 km",
                         "value":28661
                     },
                     "duration":{
                         "text":"49 mins",
                         "value":2940
                     },
                     "status":"OK"
                  }
              ]
          }
       ],
       "status":"OK"
  }
```

You can do the similar thing in Maps JavaScript API. Please have a look at this example that calculates routes using the directions service with place IDs:

http://jsbin.com/xuyisem/1/edit?html,output

You can easily apply this approach for distance matrix.

Hope it helps!